# Rewriting series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to rewrite the following product of series

$$(\sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} x^p)( \sum\limits_{q=0}^{\infty} x^{3q})
(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty} x^r)$$

i know how to rewrite the first and the last one toghether:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n$$

but adding the middle one is the problem. I need to rewrite it to be in a sum notation and not like this $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^3)}$

Comment: See [OEIS A$001840$](http://oeis.org/A001840) and [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be approached in two ways. First way: top-down. We have:
$$\left(\sum_{p\geq 0}x^{p}\right)\left(\sum_{q\geq 0}x^{q}\right)\left(\sum_{r\geq 0}x^{3r}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n)\,x^n \tag{1}$$
where:
$$ r(n) = \#\left\{(p,q,r)\in\mathbb{N}^3: p+q+3r=n\right\}.\tag{2} $$
We have:
$$ r(n) = \sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor}\#\left\{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n-3r\right\}=\sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor}(n-3r+1)$$
so:
$$ r(n) = (n+1)\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)-\frac{3}{2}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor.\tag{3}$$
Second way: bottom-up. The residue theorem provides the following partial fraction decomposition:

$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^3)} = \frac{1}{9}\frac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}+\frac{1}{9}\frac{8-7x+2x^2}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1 + x - 2 x^2}{1-x^3}+\frac{8-7x+2x^2}{(1-x)^3}\right)\tag{4} $$
hence:
$$ r(n) = \frac{n^2}{6}+\frac{5 n}{6}+\frac{8+h(n)}{9},\qquad h(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}1 &\text{if}& n\equiv 0\pmod{3}\\1 &\text{if}& n\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\-2&\text{if}&n\equiv 2\pmod{3}\end{array}\right.\tag{5} $$
and we have just to check that $(3)$ and $(5)$ are, indeed, the same expression, that simplifies to:
$$ r(n) = \left\lfloor\frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{6}\right\rfloor. \tag{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
S_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k\\
S_2 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k y^k
$$
where $a_k = k+1, b_k=1$ and $y=x^3$. You can obtain the convolution in the exact same way as with the two other sums.

Comment: but how do I rewite them?

Comment: just find the coefficients of $x^k$, e.g. for $x^3$ it will be $a_0 + a_1 +a_2 +a_3$ because all $b_k=1$. Be careful though because you have fewer terms in $S_2$, so some terms will be missing.